# input checkboxes/radio buttons slow response on tablet/mobile

Tags: html, input

When touching input checkboxes, on tablet or mobile, the response is slow, and not instant. Is there anything that can be done to increase the speed of the response time? I'm styling my radio buttons in the style of IOS like below.

```
<div class="iradio simulation-method">
  <input name="simulation-method" id="upload-photos" value="0" checked="checked" type="radio">
  <label for="upload-photos" class="simulation-method-label-js"><svg class="icon icon_camera"><use xlink:href="#icon_camera"/></svg>Photos</label>
  <input name="simulation-method" id="scan-ipad" value="1" type="radio">
  <label for="scan-ipad" class="simulation-method-label-js"><svg class="icon icon_ipad"><use xlink:href="#icon_ipad"/></svg>Scan</label>
</div>
```

a bit like this example:
https://codepen.io/wesruv/pen/vexkd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the normal behavior, because Safari is waiting a bit to know if the user wants to tap the radio button, or wants to double-tap on the zone where the radio button is (zooming).
This behavior can be disabled using CSS: `touch-action: manipulation;`
You can apply this to inputs, labels... or to the html tag so there won't be any delay on taps, even on links.